# How to make user select only certain part of entire photo

Tags: html, css

I want to make user select a photo. When he chooses it, he must have the option to crop a certain part of photo. Because every photo is not the same size as I want it. So user must have option for that.

#### For example when a photo looks like this

```
P=======================================P
||..................................... ||
||..................................... ||
||........... 11111111111...............||
||............11111111111...............||
||............11111111111...............||
||......................................||
||......................................||
||......................................||
||......................................||
P========================================P
```

#### Consider P as the corners of the photo

#### I want only the part where `ones(1)` are there

How can I achieve that. For clear Understanding, I have uploaded a screenshot how Whatsapp does it. I want it the same way.

See this screenshot of whatsapp, I need just the face, as shown here.
Remember I dont want face to be detected automatically, it should be selected by user only.

This is the screenshot
https://photos.app.goo.gl/UZx4k4YQFSNg1JMt5

Comment: What have you tried? You probably want to look at a html5 canvas widget.

Comment: I have no idea how it works. So, yet Nothing. Yeah, I will look for html5 canvas widget

Answer (score 1):

An option could be to use html map area

```html
<img src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x150" alt="imagemap" usemap="#imagemap">

<map name="imagemap">
  <area shape="rect" coords="100,100,200,200" alt="Sun" href="#" >
</map>
```

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_area.asp

**edit:** if you are looking for a custom cropper this js library can help you https://fengyuanchen.github.io/cropperjs/

Comment: Remember I dont want face to be detected automatically, it should be selected by `user` only.

Comment: This library can help you then https://fengyuanchen.github.io/cropperjs/